# are casts overridable operations? if so, how?

Tags: c++, casting, overriding

Is it possible to override (C-style) casts in C++?

Suppose I have the code

```
double x = 42;
int k = (int)x;
```

Can I make the cast in the second line execute some code I wrote? Something like

```
// I don't know C++
// I have no idea if this has more syntax errors than words
operator (int)(double) {
    std::cout << "casting from double to int" << std::endl;
}
```

<sup>The reason I ask is because of the question ["Is there any way to get gcc or clang to warn on explicit casts?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318646/is-there-any-way-to-get-gcc-or-clang-to-warn-on-explicit-casts) and my suggestion there.</sup>

Comment: Maybe if it's a cast from your own class.

Comment: I suppose it is for user-defined classes, but not for built-in types. Which one do you care about?

Comment: No, you cannot override any operators for built-in types. They are all predefined by the compiler.

Comment: If it could work for you, you could make a small container class for your double and provide an `operator int()` cast for it. That's the closest I can see it coming.

Comment: +1 simply for: "I have no idea if this has more syntax errors than words"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> § 12.3.1/1 "Type conversions of class objects can be specified by constructors and by conversion functions. These conversions are called user-defined conversions and are used for implicit type conversions (Clause 4), for initialization (8.5), and for explicit type conversions (5.4, 5.2.9)."

Yes, we can make conversions, but only if one or both sides is a user-defined type, so we can't make one for `double` to `int`.

```
struct demostruct {
    demostruct(int x) :data(x) {} //used for conversions from int to demostruct
    operator int() {return data;} //used for conversions from demostruct to int
    int data;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    demostruct ds = argc; //conversion from int to demostruct
    return ds; //conversion from demostruct to int
}
```

As Robᵩ pointed out, you can add the `explicit` keyword to either of those conversion functions, which requires the user to explicitly cast them with a `(demostruct)argc` or `(int)ds` like in your code, instead of having them implicitly convert.  If you convert to and from the same type, it's usually best to have one or both as `explicit`, otherwise you might get compilation errors.

Comment: You're the only person to look at it from the `int`'s point of view :)

Comment: @chris: His question didn't mention any type specifically outside of the samples, and `int` is my default type :P  I probably would have used `int` even if he didn't.

Comment: I mean well sure you can make a `MyDouble` class, but you can also make a `MyInt` class with a double constructor. It's close enough to draw the comparison.

Comment: @chris : "You're the only person to have included a [conversion constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384007/conversion-constructor-vs-conversion-operator-precedence)." FTFY.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but only for your own types. Look at this:

```
#include <iostream>
struct D {
  // "explicit" keyword requires C++11
  explicit operator int() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
};

int main () {
  int i;
  D d;
  //i = d;
  i = (int)d;
}
```

So, you cannot create `double::operator int()`, but you could create `MyDouble::operator int()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can’t overload operators for built-in types, but you can write a conversion operator for a user-defined type:

```
struct Double {
    double value;
    operator int() const {
        shenanigans();
        return value;
    }
};
```

Since your question arose from a need to find explicit casts in code, also be aware that C++ has explicit casting operators. These are not only clearer than C-style casts, but also eminently searchable:

```
static_cast<T>(x)      // Cast based on static type conversion.
dynamic_cast<T>(x)     // Cast based on runtime type information.
const_cast<T>(x)       // Add or remove const or volatile qualification.
reinterpret_cast<T>(x) // Cast between unrelated pointer and integral types.
```

Comment: Note that you should know when to use the explicit casts before using them. Specifically things like `const_cast`.

Comment: @chris: Well, yes, but having to know what you’re doing is a good thing. With a C-style cast, it’s much easier to do something you didn’t intend.

Comment: definitely! Just better to be aware though. Usually things are `const` for a reason.

Comment: @chris: Naturally. And since everything that can reasonably be `const` probably should be, `const_cast<T*>(x)` appropriately conveys “here be dragons”; `(T*)x` does not.

Answer (score 1):

Conversions to other types are overloadable operators in C++ ([some examples here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr383.htm)), but this fact will not help you.

Stroustrup [wanted](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/whitespace98.pdf) the language to be extensible, but not mutable.  Therefore, overloading an operator only extends the operations to new types, but you cannot redefine what happens with any old types.

"*However, to avoid absurdities, it is (still) not allowed to provide new meanings for the built-in operators for built-in types. Thus, the language remains extensible but not mutable.*"